# Counting variable in JS that has been parsed from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got a variable that represents required number of items and counting of dropped items inside droppable area. You can view example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/ow29t4t7/30/).  So what I want is to pass a variable to javascript and then calculate the difference.

I put my variable into `div`:

```
<div id="numbr" >10</div>
```

And here is the js code which counts dropped items and displays the total:

```
var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length -1;
$(this).closest("div.proc").find("div.dropped").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");
```

My goal is to find differences between `<div class="numbr">` and `n`, and then display it. How can I achieve this in js?
It is just an example.
In my system, the number is a php variable received from user's input. There could be more than 2 boxes: it depends on user's input.

Comment: `var number = parseInt($("#numbr").text(), 10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in both the drop event and the click event:

```
var proc = $(this).closest("div.proc");
    proc.find('.dif').text('Difference ' +(proc.find('.numbr').text() - n));
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d1ddsj8m/2/

```js
   var itm = [];
   $("#savebutton").click(function() {
     LISTOBJ.saveList();
   });
   $("#myAccordion").accordion({
     heightStyle: "content",
     active: false,
     collapsible: true
   });
   $("#myAccordion li").draggable({
     appendTo: "body",
     helper: "clone",
     start: function(ev, ui) {
       ui.helper.width($(this).width());
     }
   });

   $(".projLeader ol").droppable({
     tolerance: 'pointer',
     hoverClass: 'highlight',
     drop: function(ev, ui) {
       var zz = ui.draggable.text()
       var xyz = itm.includes(zz);
       if (xyz === false) {
         var item = ui.draggable;
         if (!ui.draggable.closest('.placeholder').length) item = item.clone().draggable(); // if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
         //this.innerHTML = '';                                                              // clean the placeholder
         item.addClass('dropClass').appendTo(this);
         // append item to placeholder   
         //add to array
         itm.push(zz);
         var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
         $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropped").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");
         $(this).closest("div.proc").find('.dif').text('Difference ' + ($(this).closest("div.proc").find('.numbr').text() - n));


       } else {
         alert('Name is Already Exist');
       }

     }
   });
   $(".projLeader").on('click', '.closer', function() {
     var item = $(this).closest('.item');
     var element = $("#myAccordion ul li").filter(function() {
       return $(this).text() == item.text();
     });
     itm.splice(item);
     var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length - 1;
     $(this).closest("div.proc").find("div.dropped").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");
     $(this).closest("div.proc").find('.dif').text('Difference ' + ($(this).closest("div.proc").find('.numbr').text() - n));
     item.fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
       item.remove();
     })
   });

   var LISTOBJ = {
     saveList: function() {
       var listCSV = "";
       $(".projLeader li").each(function() {
         if (listCSV === "") {
           listCSV = $(this).text();
         } else {
           listCSV += ", " + $(this).text();
         }
         $("#output").text(listCSV);
         $(".hiddenListInput").val(listCSV);
       });
     }
   }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
  height: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #cd8;
  position: relative;
}
.item .closer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 2px;
  font: bold 14px arial;
  color: #666;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.item .closer:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.placeholder {
  height: 30px;
  width: 195px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
}
.placeholder .item {
  margin: 0;
}
ol .item .closer {
  display: block;
}
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fff;
}
.highlight .item {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging {
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.dropClass {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.dropped {
  display: inline;
}
.dif {
  display: inline;
}
.numbr {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>
<div id="myAccordion">
  <h3><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Lolcat Shirt</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Buckit Shirt</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Bags</a></h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Zebra Striped</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Black Leather</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Alligator Leather</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Gadgets</a></h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>iPhone</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>iPod</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>iPad</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='proc'><pre>
<br /></pre>
  <div class="projLeader">
    <label>Box1. Required number:
      <div class="numbr">10</div>.
      <div class="dropped"></div>
      <div class="dif">Difference:</div>
    </label>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
      <ol>
        <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"></li>
        <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" />
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='proc'><pre>
<br /></pre>
  <div class="projLeader">
    <label>Box2. Required number:
      <div class="numbr">5</div>.
      <div class="dropped"></div>
      <div class="dif">Difference:</div>
    </label>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
      <ol>
        <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"></li>
        <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" />
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>

<input type="submit" id="savebutton" class="button" value="Save" onclick="userSubmitted = true;" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Please post the code here in a stack snippet instead of on jsfiddle.

Comment: you like to see some spaghetti code in my i answer? i don't

Comment: @Barmar the important part of the code is placed here

Comment: But if you're going to make an executable demo, why put it on an external site instead of putting it here?

Comment: That's why they created stack snippets, so we wouldn't have to depend on jsfiddle any more.

Comment: @Barmar persistent aren't you , here

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using jQuery, which makes it really easy to manipulate the DOM dynamically.

Here is what I would do.  First, add a difference div which will hold the difference of `n` and `numbr`:

```
<div id="numbr">10</div>
<div id="difference"></div>
```

And in your JS, calculate the difference and add it to the div:

```
var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length - 1;
var difference = parseInt($('#numbr').text(), 10) - n;
if (difference >= 0) {
    $('#difference').text('Difference ' + difference);
}
```

Comment: `$(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length - 1;` will give you the number of `.dropClass` nodes `- 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you can use a PHP variable in javascript. If that's the case, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$myVariable = 200;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myvar = <?= $myVariable; ?>;
    $(document).on('change', '.numbr', function () {
        var number = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        var difference = myvar - number;
        $('.somediv').text($difference);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="numbr">20</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the `dropClass` content, use the `text()` method. `length` will give you the number of nodes for the given selector, it's not what you want here.

You can get the `numbr` and `dropClass` content with the `text()` method.

Try this(added some html for the snippet to work):

```js
inner = $('#innerproc').closest("div.proc");
numbr = $('#numbr').text();
n = inner.find(".dropClass").text();
inner.find("div.dropped").text("Items Dropped: " + (n - numbr) + ".");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numbr">10</div>
<div class="proc">
  <div id="innerproc"></div>
  <div class="dropClass">21</div>
  <div class="dropped"></div>
</div>
```